# MYSQL does not work

Tags: php, mysql

Currently working in PHP to do this. If needed I can send across my full php code

```
Error: UPDATE `WWM_Login` SET `Username`=RyzeAlchemist1,`Email`=smadger@live.co.uk,`FirstName`=test,`MiddleName`=test,`LastName`=test,`DiscordID`=@RyzeAlchemist#6043,`P_openCompletedOrders`=1,`P_openCurrentOrders`=1,`P_openRequestedOrders`=1,`P_openCreateAnOrder`=1,`P_OpenEditUsers`=0,`P_CreateStaff`=1,`P_CreateClient`= WHERE UserID = ''
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@live.co.uk,`FirstName`=test,`MiddleName`=test,`LastName`=test,`DiscordID`=@Ryze' at line 1
```

Code:

```
UPDATE `WWM_Login` SET `Username`=$uid,`Email`=$email,`FirstName`=$firstname,`MiddleName`=$middlename,`LastName`=$lastname,`DiscordID`=$DiscordID,`P_openCompletedOrders`=$field[1],`P_openCurrentOrders`=$field[2],`P_openRequestedOrders`=$field[3],`P_openCreateAnOrder`=$field[4],`P_OpenEditUsers`=$field[5],`P_CreateStaff`=$field[6],`P_CreateClient`=$field[7] WHERE UserID = '$id'
```

Comment: Strings needs to be quoted.

Comment: Single or double quotes?

Comment: Do you have single or double quotes around the SQL querystring? Either should be good, but some engines don't like singlequotes (or so I've heard, never had an issue with it myself though)